# is this possible to make mobile app that run on web? and can be installed on mobile too?

Tags: android, ios, html

is it possible to make such mobile app that will run on website and can also be installed on mobile(both android and iPhone).kindly guide me if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  There are a few tools for that.  A good option is to go with Phonegap.  If you already know how to build an HTML5 web app, you can use Phonegap or the Phonegap Build service to turn it into a mobile app.

Also, Intel has a tool called XDK that allows you to build mobile-ready apps using a visual layout manager and HTML5 technology.  XDK lets you move your project over to a variety of mobile devices.

Both of these technologies will port over to both Android and iOS.  Be warned, though, if you have no experience developing mobile or web apps, there's a bit of a learning curve.

I recommend getting started with a good tutorial on HTML5 development (*Head First HTML/CSS*, *Head First Javascript Programming*, *Head First jQuery* are good books for beginners).

*Bootstrap* is a great system for creating a web page that works well in both mobile and PC formats.

Here are links to Intel's and PhoneGap's tools:

[Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/)

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Best of luck!

Comment: thanks  for the answer.and yes i can work on android app devlopment,n i know html,css,javascript.but will learn html5.so hope it will be easy for me :) tahnks once again for the links :)

Comment: No problem. All HTML5 is, is Javascript with some new special libraries for stuff like geolocation, local storage, easy animation scripting, etc. If you don't need any of that you're good to go. If you need database storage, obviously you're going to need a web stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is a platform for building native mobile apps using JavaScript/HTML/CSS but I believe it would be difficult to run those apps in the browser in the same manner.

http://cordova.apache.org/